# error message is not working in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I developed this simple form to test react-hook-form, but the error messages are not shown.
what am I missing here?

`

import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';

function Form3 () {
const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(`
    Name is ${data.firstName}
    Language is ${data.language}
    Age is ${data.age}
    `)
}

return(
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} dir="ltr">
        <input placeholder="Enter your name:" {...register("firstName", {
            required: {
                value: true,
                message: "Name is required!"
            },
            minLength: {
                value: 3,
                message: "Name must be at least 3 char long!"
            },
            maxLength: {
                value: 10,
                message: "Name must be at most 10 char long!"
            }
        })} />
        <br />
        <select {...register("language")}>
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option value="fa">Persian</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input type="number" {...register("age", {
            min: {
                value: 10,
                message: "you should be at least 10 years old!"
            },
            max: {
                value: 50,
                message: "you should be at most 50 years old!"
            }
        })} />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
);
```

}

export default Form3;

`

Comment: At no point are you actually rendering errors. You'll need to get the formState.errors object from useForm and use the subfields from it.

Comment: what do you mean by error is not showing on alert? if you need the error displayed at the bottom you have to add `{errors?.firstName?.type === "required" && <p>This field is required</p>}` also please go through the documentation all your queries will be solved.